Convert from one curve to another
How can I convert from one curve to another curve using X points, are there any formulas for that?
p = next_prime(2 ** 4)
K = GF(p)
E1 = EllipticCurve(K, (0, 6))
E2 = EllipticCurve(K, (0, 7))
G1 = E1.gen(0)
G2 = E2.gen(0)

for i in range(E1.order()):
    print(i * G1, 'Convert To :', i * G2)


Are you sure the curves are isomorphic, or at least, birationally equivalent to another? Are you sure the point $X$ exists on both curves?

An even less strict notion that would help here could be $E_1$ and $E_2$ being isogenous, i.e. there exists (and can be constructed due to Velu) a rational map between $E_1$ and $E_2$ , where there exists its "dual" (and not a proper inverse like in birational equivalence) that their composition gives the multiplication map by the degree of the isogeny. By Sato and Tate, two elliptic curves over finite fields are isogenous iff the have the same number of rational points.

Can you provide code example?
